# How to find which elements are in the bag, using Knapsack Algorithm [and not only the bag's value]?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Here I have code which calculates the optimal value using the knapsack algorithm (bin packing NP-hard problem):

```
int Knapsack::knapsack(std::vector<Item>& items, int W)
{
    size_t n = items.size();
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > dp(W + 1, std::vector<int>(n + 1, 0));
    for (size_t j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        for ( int w = 1; w <= W; w++)
        {
            if (items[j-1].getWeight() <= w)
            {
                dp[w][j] = std::max(dp[w][j-1], dp[w - items[j-1].getWeight()][j-1] + items[j-1].getWeight());
            }
            else
            {
                dp[w][j] = dp[w][j - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[W][n];
}
```

I also need the elements included in the pack to be shown. I want to create an array to put the chosen elements. So the question is, in which step can I perform this selection? Is there any other more efficient way to determine which items have been taken?

I want to be able to know the items that give me the optimal solution, and not just the value of the best solution.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand your question, but I guess you want to be able to know the items that give you the optimal solution, and not just the value of the best solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Getting the elements you packed from the matrix can be done using the data from the matrix without storing any additional data.

Pseudo code:

```
line <- W
i <- n
while (i > 0):
  if dp[line][i] - dp[line - weight(i)][i-1] == value(i):
      // the element 'i' is in the knapsack
      i <- i-1 // only in 0-1 knapsack
      line <- line - weight(i)
  else: 
      i <- i-1
```

The idea behind it is that you iterate the matrix; if the weight difference is exactly the element's size, it is in the knapsack. If it is not, the item is not in the knapsack, go on without it.

Comment: It's really nice pseudo code. But using it i can get only the weight of added element, and i need their name also. I'm thinking about doint the same, but to change array `dp` to an `Item` type. What's your point about it?

Comment: @nightcrime: Using this alorithm, you know EXACTLY which element is in the bag, you can create a container before you start this algorithm [let's call it `bag`, and while running the algorithm: if `dp[line][i] - dp[line][i-1] == value(i)` then `bag.add(items[i-1])`, where `items` is the input vector of items to your knapsack function. At the end of the algorithm, `bag` will contain all the elements in the bag, and only them.

Comment: :I've got it. But it works only and only if i've added only 1 element. In other ways the statement dp[line][i] - dp[line][i-1] == value(i) never is true.(

Comment: @nightcrime: I am not sure I am following you, the knapsack algorithm, and so does my answer, doesn't allow you to add the item 'i' to the bag twice [or 3/4/.. times]. if you add elements i,j,k: this algorithm will find all of them, since `dp[line][i]-dp[line][i-1] == value(i)`, `dp[line][j]-dp[line][j-1] == value(j)` and `dp[line][k]-dp[line][k-1] == value(k)`.

Comment: I want to clarify one thing: `value(i)` in my example is `items[i-1].getWeight()` isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I used `items[i]` instead of `items[i-1]`. Very stupid mistake:) Thanks, you really rescued me:)

Comment: you could also simply check if `dp[line][i] != dp[line][i-1]`. if that is true, then the ith item is taken.

Comment: Be careful when doing `line - weight(i)` as weight of some items may be larger than the knapsack i.e it may give a negative index.

Answer (score 2):

```
line <- W
i <- n
while (i> 0):
  if dp[line][i] - dp[line - weight(i) ][i-1] == value(i):
    the element 'i' is in the knapsack
    cw = cw - weight(i)
    i <- i-1
  else if dp[line][i] > dp[line][i-1]:
    line <- line - 1
  else: 
    i <- i-1
```

Just remember how you got to dp[line][i] when you added item i

```
dp[line][i] = dp[line - weight(i) ][i - 1] + value(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm for reconstructing items taken in bounded 0/1 knapsack is simpler than some of the existing code in this thread may lead one to believe. This answer aims to demystify the procedure a bit and provide a clean, direct implementation alongside a worked example.

---

#### The approach

Begin with two indices respective to the table axes: a `weight` variable initialized to the knapsack capacity and an index `i` that loops backwards over the DP lookup table along the item axis, stopping at index 1 (the algorithm uses `i-1` so stopping at 1 avoids an out of bounds access).

In the loop, if `T[weight][i] != T[weight][i-1]`, mark item `i-1` as selected, deduct its weight and continue stepping backwards along the item axis.

Time complexity of the reconstruction is `O(length(items))`.

Here is Python as pseudocode:

```py
def reconstruct_taken_items(T, items, capacity):
    taken = []
    weight = capacity

    for i in range(len(items), 0, -1): # from n downto 1 (inclusive)
        if T[weight][i] != T[weight][i-1]:
            taken.append(items[i-1])
            weight -= items[i-1].weight

   return taken
```

---

#### Example

For example, consider a knapsack capacity of 9 and these items:

```
[item(weight=1, value=2), 
 item(weight=3, value=5), 
 item(weight=4, value=8), 
 item(weight=6, value=4)]
```

The best value is 15 by taking items 0, 1 and 2.

The DP lookup table is

```
items ---->

0  1  2  3  4
--------------+
0  0  0  0  0 | 0  capacity
0  2  2  2  2 | 1     |
0  2  2  2  2 | 2     |
0  2  5  5  5 | 3     v
0  2  7  8  8 | 4
0  2  7 10 10 | 5
0  2  7 10 10 | 6
0  2  7 13 13 | 7
0  2  7 15 15 | 8
0  2  7 15 15 | 9
```

Run the reconstruction algorithm on this:

```
0  0  0  0  0
0  2  2  2  2
0  2  2  2  2
0  2  5  5  5
0  2  7  8  8
0  2  7 10 10
0  2  7 10 10
0  2  7 13 13
0  2  7 15 15
0  2  7 15 15 <-- weight = capacity = 9
        ^   ^
        |   |
      i-1   i = length(items) = 4
```

In the initial state above, `T[weight][i] == T[weight][i-1]` (`15 == 15`) so `item[i-1]` (`item(weight=6, value=4)`) wasn't taken. Decrement `i` and try the remaining items with the same capacity.

```
0  0  0  0  0
0  2  2  2  2
0  2  2  2  2
0  2  5  5  5
0  2  7  8  8
0  2  7 10 10
0  2  7 10 10
0  2  7 13 13
0  2  7 15 15
0  2  7 15 15 <-- weight = 9
        ^
        |
        i = 3
```

Here, `T[weight][i] != T[weight][i-1]` (`7 != 15`) so `items[i-1]`, which is `items[2]`, or `item(weight=4, value=8)`, must have been taken. Decrement the weight remaining by `items[i-1].weight`, or `9 - 4 = 5`, and try the remaining items with the smaller weight left over after taking `item[i-1]` out of the picture.

```
0  0  0  0  0
0  2  2  2  2
0  2  2  2  2
0  2  5  5  5
0  2  7  8  8
0  2  7 10 10 <-- weight = 5
0  2  7 10 10
0  2  7 13 13
0  2  7 15 15
0  2  7 15 15
      ^
      |
      i = 2
```

In this state, we again have `T[weight][i] != T[weight][i-1]` (`2 != 7`) so we must have taken `items[i-1]`, which is `items[1]`, or `item(weight=3, value=5)`. Decrement the weight remaining by `items[i-1].weight`, or `5 - 3`, and move to the next item.

```
0  0  0  0  0
0  2  2  2  2
0  2  2  2  2 <-- weight = 2
0  2  5  5  5
0  2  7  8  8
0  2  7 10 10
0  2  7 10 10
0  2  7 13 13
0  2  7 15 15
0  2  7 15 15
   ^
   |
   i = 1
```

In this last step, we again have `T[weight][i] != T[weight][i-1]` (`0 != 2`) so we must have taken `items[i-1]`, which is `items[0]`, or `item(weight=1, value=2)`. Decrement the weight remaining by `items[i-1].weight`, or `2 - 1`, and exit the loop because `i == 0`.

---

#### C++ implementation

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Knapsack {
public:
    struct Item {
        const int weight;
        const int value;
    };

private:
    static std::vector<Item> reconstruct_taken_items(
        const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &T,
        const std::vector<Item> &items,
        const int capacity
    ) {
        std::vector<Item> taken;
        int weight = capacity;
    
        for (size_t i = items.size(); i > 0; i--) {
            if (T[weight][i] != T[weight][i-1]) {
                taken.emplace_back(items[i-1]);
                weight -= items[i-1].weight;
            }
        }
    
        return taken;
    }

public:
    static std::vector<Item> solve(
        const std::vector<Item> &items, 
        const int capacity
    ) {
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > T(
            capacity + 1,
            std::vector<int>(items.size() + 1, 0)
        );
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= capacity; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 1; j <= items.size(); j++) {
                const Item &item = items[j-1];

                if (item.weight > i) {
                    T[i][j] = T[i][j-1];
                }
                else {
                    T[i][j] = std::max(
                        T[i-item.weight][j-1] + item.value, 
                        T[i][j-1]
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        
        return reconstruct_taken_items(T, items, capacity);
    }
};

int main() {
    const int capacity = 9;
    const std::vector<Knapsack::Item> items = {
        {1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 8}, {6, 4}
    };

    for (const Knapsack::Item &item : Knapsack::solve(items, capacity)) {
        std::cout << "weight: " << item.weight 
                  << ", value: " << item.value << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### See also

- [Printing Items that are in sack in knapsack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186171/printing-items-that-are-in-sack-in-knapsack)
- [Knapsack 0-1 path reconstruction (which items to take)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935533/knapsack-0-1-path-reconstruction-which-items-to-take)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a julia implementation:

```
function knapsack!{F<:Real}(
    selected::BitVector,    # whether the item is selected
    v::AbstractVector{F},   # vector of item values (bigger is better)
    w::AbstractVector{Int}, # vector of item weights (bigger is worse)
    W::Int,                 # knapsack capacity (W ≤ ∑w)
    )

    # Solves the 0-1 Knapsack Problem
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem
    # Returns the assigment vector such that
    #  the max weight ≤ W is obtained

    fill!(selected, false)

    if W ≤ 0
        return selected
    end

    n = length(w)
    @assert(n == length(v))
    @assert(all(w .> 0))

    ###########################################
    # allocate DP memory

    m = Array(F, n+1, W+1)
    for j in 0:W
        m[1, j+1] = 0.0
    end

    ###########################################
    # solve knapsack with DP

    for i in 1:n
        for j in 0:W
            if w[i] ≤ j
                m[i+1, j+1] = max(m[i, j+1], m[i, j-w[i]+1] + v[i])
            else
                m[i+1, j+1] = m[i, j+1]
            end
        end
    end

    ###########################################
    # recover the value

    line = W
    for i in n : -1 : 1
        if line - w[i] + 1 > 0 && m[i+1,line+1] - m[i, line - w[i] + 1] == v[i]
            selected[i] = true
            line -= w[i]
        end
    end

    selected
end
```