# How to understand the subset-sum issue

Tags: c, algorithm, subset-sum

I was learning subset sum problem ,and i'd like to ask some question here

(1) [Subset Sum algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355955/subset-sum-algorithm)

I read the C code in this link just now,and I wonder that why author can define?

```
S[i,0]=true ,S[0,j]=false
```

`S[i,0]` means the `subset[1,...i]` that sums to `0`,why can it assign to `true`.?And how can I modify this algorithm if want to print the content of subset?
Because it seemed forbidden to chat with author privately,I have to post it .

(2)if there are negative numbers in array,I have tried to test that it is not fit.How can I define the initial value for `S[i,0]` and `S[0,j]`?

Could anyone help me to clarify?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**There is a problem with the base clause suggested**, since with it, you could also take `s[n,0]` as an initial value.

A better stop clause to the recursive formula of subset-sum is `s[i,xi] = true`. The idea is simple, the set `{x1,x2,...,xi}` contains a subset that sums to `xi` - it is the subset `{xi}`. The recursion will later on take care of the rest, and if there is a subset summing to 0, it will find it.

According to this approach, the base clause is:

```
s[i,xi] = true (for each i)
s[0,j] = false (for each j)
```

And the recursive formula is:

```
s[i,j] = s[i-1,j] OR s[i-1,j-xi]
```

---

**To get which elements are actually in the subset**, you will need to follow the matrix you built with your dynamic programming. "follow" the choices done by the matrix, and stick to a path that yields true until you find a "stop clause" (s == xi)

It can be described recursively with:

```
getSubset(i,s):
   if s[i-1,s]: //there is a solution without choosing xi
       return getSubset(i-1, s)
   if (xi == s): //true base clause
        l <- new list
        l.append(xi)
        return l
   if s[i -1, s-xi]: //there is a solution when choosing xi
        l <- getSubset(i-1,s-xi)
        l.append(xi)
        return l
```

It resembles a lot (make sure you understand why): [How to find which elements are in the bag, using Knapsack Algorithm [and not only the bag's value]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7489398/572670)

Comment: can it cost much more space if want to define s[i,xi]=true?because the value of xi may be very large.And the sum may be not so large,smaller.

Comment: @liumilan: No, it won't cost more space. At some point you will have to calculate s[i,xi] in both approaches - and thus this value must be stored anyway. Note that you raise an important issue with this solution - it is *pseudo-polynomial*, i.e. the time (and space) it consumes depends linearly on the numbers in the subsets - which are exponential in the number of bits needed to represent them.