# Finding a set of numbers equals to the number

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to write a c# program that does following:

1. Takes two parameters: a list of objects and a number
2. Iterates through the list and find the first set of objects that equals to the number.
3. Stop iteration if a set is found and the return the set.

So, I have a list of user defined object, say Person as an example.  Say, Person object has two fields, Name and age. For example,

```
MyList
-   Person1: John, 10
-   Person2: Mary, 25
-   Person3: Mike, 35
-   Person4: Ann, 20
-   Person5: Joe, 5
```

I want to find a set from the list that equals to the number that I am passing in.  If I am passing in above list and 50, I want to return Person2, Person4, Person5 as a list.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: You say you are "trying to write", so show us what you have tried, and what doesn't work.

Comment: @Romoku: Which in itself is not a problem. The problem here is that the OP didn't try anything himself or at least he doesn't show us what he tried and what the problems with this were.

Comment: The keyword to search here is "0/1 knapsack problem".

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to return Person1, 3 and 5? 10 + 35 + 5 is also 50.

Comment: This us [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). It is NP-Complete and can be solved using brute force on `O(2^n)` or using DP on `O(W*n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in the input set, and `W` is the input number.

Comment: Sorry everyone that I wasnt clear.  I was just thinking it and wasnt clear how I could achieve this.  I will look at both knapsack and subset sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Unfortunately, it is NP-Complete, so there is no known polynomial solution for it.

However, it does have a [pseudo-polynomial solution, using Dyanamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution), that is using the next recursive function:

```
f(i,0) = true
f(0,k) = false (k != 0)
f(i,k) = f(i-1,k) or f(i-1,k-weight[i])
```

Running with `f(n,W)` yields true if such solution exists, and false otherwise.

The dynamic programming solution fills up a table, after the table is full, you need to "retrace" your steps from `table[n][W]` back in order to find which items should be included in the set.

More information on getting the actual elements from the table can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7489398/572670)