# How to find elements in the Knapsack (twist- need to ALL ways of getting element)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

This is a classic Knapsack problem which I have solved using a Dynamic Programming approach.

Following on from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489398/how-to-find-which-elements-are-in-the-bag-using-knapsack-algorithm-and-not-onl), I have a created a similar way to determine the type of elements that constitute the Knapsack. I need to find out ALL the ways the final answer can be gotten, not just one way. How can I do this?

Currently, I can only work backwards to find one way in which my items added to the max value. But in my input, I may have 2 or more ways in which items add to the max value. I want to know these 2 or more ways because then I have to choose an optimal set of items based on some criteria. How can I do this? Should I work on my DP matrix or my code below?

> e.g. input
>
> constraint:
>
> maxWeight = 100
>
> i.d./ value / weight
>
> 1/50/40
>
> 2/40/30
>
> 3/30/40
>
> 4/50/40
>
> Output: based on constraint, I can have 1,2,3 or 2,3,4
>
> Both add up to the same score and weight. How can I determine both
>   sets?

Prelude:

> I am determining if the item's time property in the arraylist falls
>   within a certain limit. I have created a bool array (wasTaken) in my
>   knapsack method where I put in the elements which could have been
>   taken. Here I traverse my matrix to determine which element was taken,
>   and then store the item's id for print (after sorting) later. int[][]
>   sol below represents the matrix populated in a Dynamic Programming
>   style from prior method. The i values represent items and the Weight
>   values represent the weights being considered. This has been done in a
>   manner similar to [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/) link.

My current code:

```
public static void findElements(boolean[][] wasTaken, int maxWeight, ArrayList<Nodes> items, int[][] sol, int currentTime, int limit) {
        int K = maxWeight;
        int n = items.size();
        int count = 0;
        int[] forPrint = new int[n];
        for (int i = n-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if (wasTaken[i][K] == true && (currentTime - items.get(i).time <= limit)) {
                forPrint[i] = items.get(i).index;
                count++;
                K = K - items.get(i).height;

            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(forPrint);
        showResult(count, forPrint);
    }
```

Comment: The weights, max and sets are inconsistent.

Comment: thanks for pointing out but i don't think so, i get the correct answers when i run my code..

Answer (score 0):

For `j` from `1` to `n`, let `p[j]` be the profit of item `j` and let `w[j]` be the weight. For `j` from `0` to `n` and `W` from `0` up to the weight limit, let `opt[j][W]` be the maximum total profit choosing items from `1..j` of total weight not greater than `W`. In computing `opt`, we have the recurrence

```
opt[j][W] = max(p[j] + opt[j - 1][W - w[j]],   opt[j - 1][W])    if j > 0 and W ≥ 0,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       item j chosen         item j not chosen
            0                                                    if j = 0 and W ≥ 0,
            -infinity (i.e., infeasible)                         if W < 0.
```

To enumerate *all* optimal solution, we work recursively and depth-first. Given `j` and `W`, if this is a base case, then yield the current set of chosen items (if `W ≥ 0`) or nothing at all (if `W < 0`). Otherwise, compare `opt[j][W]` with both arguments of the max. If it's equal to the first argument, then yield all solutions for `j - 1` and `W - w[j]` with item `j` added to the set of chosen items. If `opt[j][W]` is equal to the second argument, then yield all solutions for `j - 1` and `W`. We can yield multiple solutions because both arguments may be equal.

Comment: thanks David. I understand this recurrence relation and am using it actually in my 'prior' method mentioned above. But how do I retrieve these sets of elements?