# find items in knapsack bag

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, knapsack-problem

I want to solve the knapsack problem recursively in C#. This is my code:

```
public  int f(int n, int remain)
{
    if (n < 0) return 0;
    if (w[n] > remain)
    {
        //    Thread.VolatileWrite(ref   check[n], 0);
        check[n] = 0;
        return f(n - 1, remain);
    }
    else
    {
        int a = f(n - 1, remain);
        int b = p[n] + f(n - 1, remain - w[n]);
        if (a >= b)
        {
            //   Thread.VolatileWrite(ref   check[n], 0);
            check[n] = 0;
            return a;
        }
        else
        {
            //  Thread.VolatileWrite(ref   check[n], 1);
            check[n] = 1;
            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

`w` is an array that holds weights and `p` is an array that holds prices. `n` is the number of items and `remain` is the maximum weight.

My problem is with the `check` array. I have used this array to store items that are going to be in the bag but it does not work always, sometimes the solution is right and sometimes not. I have tried everything but could not figure it out. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please include a specific input for which the actual result differs from the desired result. What is the return value of `f`? The weight of a found solution?

Comment: The return value should be right. Take care of modifying the check array inside the recursion. Try to copy the array every time, and return  it in a tuple. It is not optimal, but you can see it better

Comment: @codor w is an array that consists of wights and p is an array consists of prices...n is the number of items and remain is maximum wight

Comment: @rpax yeah the return value is right....i don not get what u r suggesting could u give me an example?

Comment: I am on the mobile phone right now...

Comment: ok in your convenience time...thanks

Comment: please vote up @amit 's answer. Thats what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of the check array is wrong, since it indicates the last assignment, and it does not have to be the one chosen.

Here is a counter example that explains why it does not work.

Assume:

```
weights = [1,2]
values = [2,1]
w = 2
```

Now, let examine what will happen:

```
f(1,2):
   f(0,2):
       f(-1,2)  = 0
       a = 0
       f(-1,1) = 0
       b = 2 + 0 = 2
       b>a -> check[0] = 1
    return f(0,2) = 2
    a = 2
    f(0,0):
       w[0] > 0: check[0] = 0
       return f(-1,0) = 0
    return f(0,0) = 0
    b = 1 + 0 = 1
    a > b: check[1] = 0
return  f(1,2) = 2
```

So, the optimal solution to this problem is 2 (chosing the 2nd element), but your solution chose no element (check = [0,0])

This happens because the changing of `check` is global, and not local to the calling environment, and specifically - the assignment in deep levels do not depend on the choice you made in higher levels.

To handle it you can either:

1. make your list not global, and each recursive call will have its own
   instance of a list. The "parent" call will chose not only which
   value to take, but according to this choice - the parent will also
   chose the list it will use, and append "his" choice to it, before forwarding  up to its parent.
2. Switch to a [DP solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem), or mimic the DP solution, and then use the table you created to figure out which elements to chose as I described in this thread: [How to find which elements are in the bag, using Knapsack Algorithm [and not only the bag's value]?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7489482/572670)

Comment: Good answer. I love the answers to homework questions that are not _here is the code_ answers, teaching how to think and solve the problem. Thanks for making this site better.

Comment: @amit sorry to ask for the code......but a little more hint wont hurt about the first solution u suggested