# Getting list of selected items in Knapsack DP matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I have tried implementing stack Overflow [Answered Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489398/how-to-find-which-elements-are-in-the-bag-using-knapsack-algorithm-and-not-onl). But it is not working.

**TEST CASE :**

```
   int val[] = {10,40,30,50};
   int wt[] = {5,4,6,3};
     W = 10;
```

**OUTPUT KNAPSACK DP MATRIX:**

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 
0 0 0 0 4 5 5 5 5 9 9 
0 0 0 0 4 5 6 6 6 9 10 
0 0 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

> Wt that can be reached is  : 10
>
> sum of wt of selected items : 11 **(which is wrong should be only 10)**
>
> selected -> 6 (3rd item) and 5 (1st item) **[which is wrong]**

```
int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n)
{
 int i, w;
 int K[n+1][W+1]; 
  int picks[n+1][W+1] = {0};
  // Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
   {
   for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
   {
       if (i==0 || w==0)
           K[i][w] = 0;
       else if (wt[i-1] <= w){
          //val[i-1 ] is value of curr i
             K[i][w] = max(wt[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]],  K[i-1][w]);
             if (val[i-1]+K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]] > K[i-1][w]){
                picks[i][w]=1;
             }
            else
                picks[i][w]=-1;
       }
       else{
        // wt of individual is > limit 
             picks[i][w] = -1; 
             K[i][w] = K[i-1][w];
    }
   }
  }
}
```

For printing the picked elements , I am using

```
while (w > 0 && i > 0 ){

if ((K[i][w] - K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]]) == wt[i-1]){
    weight += wt[i-1];
    i = i - 1;
    w = w - wt[i-1];
}
else{
  i = i - 1;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 w =  w - wt[i-1]
```

is actually

```
w =  w - wt[i-2]
```

since the i = i - 1 is computed before it.
Below code will work now.

```
    weight += wt[i-1];
    i = i - 1;
    w = w - wt[i] ;
```