# Reverse 0/1 knapsack: how is this row in the table possible?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm solving a reverse 0/1 knapsack problem, i.e. I'm trying to recreate the list of weights and values of all the items using only the DP-table.

I have this table:

```
    [0][1]   [4][5][6]               [12]
[0]  0  0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[1]  0  4 4 4 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  
[2]  0  4 4 4 6 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

I don't understand how row [2] is possible.

[0] - it is clear that if we do not put anything in the knapsack, the answer total value 0.

[1] - in row [1] I see that `[1][1]=4` and I hope that I correctly conclude that the first item has `weight = 1` and `value = 4`. So, since we put only 1 item it is the only weight we can hope for in this row.

[2] - when we reach [2][4], we have 6, 6 > [2-1][4] and I assume that we use 2 items here, one `weight = 1` and `value = 4` (the old one) and `weight = 4-1` and `value = 6-4` =  `weight = 3` and `value = 2`, which is the new one.

**Question**: How is it possible to have [2][5] = 10? We can't put more than 1 item on a row, as I understand this chart. If we have two items in use here, shouldn't we have 6 for all the elements in row [2] starting from [2][4] to the end of the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems possible if you have two items, one with weight 1 and value 4 and one with weight 4, value 6.

How? When you're at index (2, 4) you have a weight capacity of 4 for the first time in the row that considers item 2 (weight 4, value 6). This lets you take the item with value 6 *instead* of the weight 1, value 4 item you previously took at index (2, 3), effectively building from the subproblem at index (2, 0).

Now, when you're at index (2, 5) with a weight capacity of 5, the total value of 10 is possible because you can take both items. That's the best you can do for the rest of the row.

---

See also [How to find which elements are in the bag, using Knapsack Algorithm [and not only the bag's value]?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66173977/6243352)