# Minimize maximum time to complete tasks in parallel

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, queue, task, minimax

Suppose there are n tasks to complete and k parallel processors that can complete the task.
Each processor can only run 1 task at a time and each processor takes a different amount of time to complete each task (we can represent the time it takes for each processor to complete each task in an n X k matrix)

What's the optimal algorithm to allocate the n tasks to the k processors to minimize the total time to complete all tasks?

Very similar to this problem:
[Algorithm to find the most efficient way to distribute non-identical work tasks between workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67875945/algorithm-to-find-the-most-efficient-way-to-distribute-non-identical-work-tasks)

But with non-identical workers!

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some more searching I learned this is integer linear programming problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).